# SVG Map zoom keep icons and tooltip normal size

Tags: dictionary, svg, zooming

I have made an SVG map with the feature to choose a soccer player and display dynamically the club where the soccer player has played. See http://527229-1.web1.fh-htwchur.ch/. When you click on "Fussballer" and then you choose a name, the position of the clubs (soccer ball icons) will be shown on the map. And when you hover over the icons, some information is displayed.

My problem is, I want to keep the icons and the tooltip unzoomed when zooming out/in (no scale). So that the text and icons keep always the same size.
For the zooming functionality I used the https://github.com/ariutta/svg-pan-zoom library, and it works fine.

I spent several days with some transforming formulas when onZoom method is called, but I couldn't get it right. Help is really appreciated. (I know that there are D3 libraries who can do the zooming too, but I want to keep svg-pan-zoom if possible).

Here is an simplified example https://jsfiddle.net/n8kLz5ty/1/.

I want that the tooltip and the text in it is staying the same size and the same position regardless of the zoom.

```
<h1>Demo for svg-pan-zoom: In-line SVG</h1>
<div id="container" style="width: 400px; height: 300px; border:1px solid black;">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="width: 400px;  height: 300px; "version="1.1" id="map-svg">
    <g id="circle">
    <circle cx="102" cy="197.5" r="20" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.1" fill="red" />
        <g id="tooltip" opacity="0.7" transform="translate(20 20)">
            <rect x="104" y="197.5" width="80" height="40" rx="5"/>
            <text x="107" y="209.5">Test</text>
        </g>
    </g>    
</svg>
</div>
<script>
    function init() {

    window.zoomTiger = svgPanZoom('#map-svg', {
      zoomEnabled: true,
      controlIconsEnabled: true,
      fit: false,
      center: true,
      minZoom: 1,
      maxZoom: 50,
      zoomScaleSensitivity: 0.5,
      onZoom: function(){   
        //in the following segment I tried with different values to counter the zoom and the transform of the tooltip, but honestly I have no clue!
        var values = svgPanZoom('#map-svg');
        var realZoom = values.getZoom();
        var viewBox = values.getSizes();
        var height = viewBox.viewBox.height;
        var y = height/2;
        var width = viewBox.viewBox.width;
        var x = width/2;
        var Zoom1 = 1.02/(realZoom+0.02);
        x = (realZoom-1)*0.95*x + 20;
        y = (realZoom-1)*0.85*y + 20;
        document.getElementById("tooltip").setAttribute("transform", "scale(" + Zoom1 + ") translate(" + x + "," + y + ")");    
       },
     });
    };
    init();

</script>
```

Comment: I updated my post a few days ago...Thanks for the input.